# Handling io::Result<DirEntry> without return on Err

Tags: rust

I am trying to handle `io::Result<DirEntry>` returned from iterating on `items` of `std::fs::read_dir()` function. My concern is how to get the value of `DirEntry` when applying `match` from `Result` when `Ok`

```
let files = match fs::read_dir(&dir_path) {
    Ok(items) => items,
    //I actually want to leave function if there is an error here
    Err(_) => return Err("Cannot read directory items".to_string()),
};
for item in files { // item: io::Result<DirEntry>
    match item {
      Ok(de) => de,// how to get `de` out of this scope??
      //here I just want to print error and loop for next item
      Err(_) => println!("{:?} cannot be accessed", item),
    };
    //do something with `de`
}
```

I tried also the following

```
  let files = match fs::read_dir(&dir_path) {
    Ok(items) => items,
    Err(_) => return Err("Cannot read directory items".to_string()),
  };

  for item in files {
    let file: DirEntry; // I get compile error for use of possibly uninitialized `file`
    match item {
      Ok(de) => file = de,
      Err(_) => println!("{:?} cannot be accessed", item),
    };
    //do somthing with file
  }
```

Maybe there is a better way for handling `Result` without using `match` in cases like this?

Comment: It looks like you don't need to get it out of that scope, you can do `Ok(de) => { /* do something with de */ },`

Comment: I know I could do this but I would like to avoid nesting as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt declaring a variable outside the `match` is on the right track. You're getting an error about a possibly uninitialized variable because you're not forcing the flow of execution to progress to the next iteration on the `Err` branch. You can do so by adding `continue` to the `Err` branch. Then the variable can be initialized in the same way as the `files` variable, by assigning the result of the `match` expression directly to the variable.

```
for item in files {
    let file = match item {
        Ok(de) => de,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("{:?} cannot be accessed", item);
            continue;
        }
    };
    // do something with file
    file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see now the necessity of `continue` here.